# Visual Studio Code - SFTP Extension Using SSH Authentication

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code

I'm using the [vscode-sftp extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp) in my Visual Studio Code workflow to upload files to my remote server, whenever I hit save. I am trying to achieve password-less authentication as I used to do with Sublime Text's [SFTP plugin](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp). However, the catch is that for vscode-sftp, in the `sftp.json` file, I have to enter my Password as plain text for this to work:

```
{
    "host": "mysamplehost.com",
    "port": 22,
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "agent": null,
    "privateKeyPath": null,
    "passphrase": null,
    "passive": false,
    "interactiveAuth": false,
    "remotePath": "/",
    "uploadOnSave": true,
    ...
}
```

However, if I SSH into my server, I do not get asked for a password - since I have the SSH key in my MacBook. How do I configure vscode-sftp to use this authentication method?

I see the following comment in the [documentation](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/blob/master/README.md#config), however I don't know how to set this up:

```
  /**
   * string - Path to ssh-agent's UNIX socket for ssh-agent-based user authentication.
   * Windows users: set to 'pageant' for authenticating with Pageant or (actual) path to a cygwin "UNIX socket.
   */
  agent: null, 
  privateKeyPath: null, // absolute path to user private key
  passphrase: null,
  passive: false, // ftp passive mode
```

Comment: mini note; if you're using AWS EC2 you must use Public IPv4 DNS adres. Not Public IPv4 address.

Comment: under macOS all I needed to do was add "agent": "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" to my config.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I figured it out after stumbling upon [this](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/18). Here is how I did it. First, run:

`$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

Enter the path to `agent` in your `sftp.json` file. Also enter the path to your private key (id_rsa file). The following config did the trick for me:

```
"agent": "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.nPw17MhOqq/Listeners",
"privateKeyPath": "/Users/amitsn/.ssh/id_rsa",
"passphrase": null,
```

Note that I do not have a passphrase, so I left it null. Do not forget to fill this one if you have one.

Comment: that agent path will change upon every reboot, the answer I found is over here [https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177419](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177419)

Comment: @Amit Is this extension officially supported by Microsoft or VSCode? Does VSCode have a built-in sftp pluging/functionality?

Comment: You can use the [environment variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) itself in the `agent` property. e.g. `"agent": "${env:SSH_AUTH_SOCK}",` Also, `"privateKeyPath"` is not a valid property, it should be `"privateKey`". If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/humy2833/FTP-Simple/blob/master/extension.js), you'll see that it's actually reading from a file.

Comment: it should be `"$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"` and not `"${env:SSH_AUTH_SOCK}"`

Comment: @DrewChapin your link doesn't display the source for sftp .. it displays only the ftp-simple source... both ways didn't work for me .. I always have to enter my passphrase .. so the agent doesn't work

Answer (score 22):

For me, it was enough to just use the `privateKeyPath` option:

```
...
    "host": "my.site",
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "port": 22,
    "username": "username",
    "privateKeyPath": "/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa",
...
```

Note: in order to login with the key, you need to install your key to the remote server first with `ssh-copy-id username@my.site` command.

Comment: This worked for me on a windows Machine too. Generated the key using putty and used the ppk like this with forward slashes:
`code`

Answer (score 5):

You could do this.

```
"agent": "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

Comment: Yep - this was all I needed to do (VS Code v1.71.0 and SFTP v1.15.14, macOS Monterey v12.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

Generate your ssh key specifying the ecdsa algorithm type: ssh-keygen -t ecdsa (Linux) PuTTY (Windows)

```
{
"name": "your_remote_server_name",
"host": "123.456.789.100",
"protocol": "sftp",
"port": 1234,
"username": "remote_user_name",
"privateKeyPath": "/home/local_user_name/.ssh/id_ecdsa",
"passphrase":true,
"remotePath": "/home/remote_user_name/folderxyz",
"uploadOnSave": true,
"useTempFile": false,
"openSsh": false
}
```

If you don't use a passphrase when generating your ssh key, remove ("passphrase":true,) from this code.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling passphrase dialog:

```
"passphrase": true,
```

Described in [Wiki](https://github.com/Natizyskunk/vscode-sftp/wiki/SFTP-only-Config). This works for Natizyskunk and liximomo.

I'm using a working [fork](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Natizyskunk.sftp) of liximomo, since I get an annoying fake error message there.